# Formic Acid vs Formica - Which came first?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, nomenclature

> [image: Etymology of Formic Acid]
>
> Source: Google(Oxford)

So, we know that 'Formic Acid' was derived in formic acid in the late 18th century from the Latin word 'formica'. From Wikipedia:

> Formica is a genus of ants of the family Formicidae, commonly known as wood ants, mound ants, thatching ants, and field ants. Formica is the type genus of the Formicidae, and of the subfamily Formicinae.

I *think* I've read in some junior classes that the biological name 'Formica' was given to ant because of the secretion of 'Formic Acid' by it which is the cause of the irritation at the stung area.

So, I want to know - Is formic acid derived from 'Formica' (ants) or are ants' (biological name) derived from the presence of 'formic acid' in them?

Comment: The acid was named after the ants it was isolated from. The Romans did not understand chemistry in the way we do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name 'formic acid' has been derived from the name '*formica*' as it is derived *literally* from ants. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formic_acid) clearly states:

> The word "formic" comes from the Latin word for ant, *formica*,
>   referring to its early isolation by the distillation of ant bodies.

If you type 'formic acid etymology' in Google, it will give two links that proves the above statement:

1. > 1791 (in formic acid), literally "from ants," coined from Latin
   >   *formica* "ant". The acid first was obtained in a fairly pure form in 1749 by German chemist Andreas Sigismund Marggraf (1709-1782), who
   >   prepared it by **distilling red ants**.([etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/formic))
2. > As early as the fifteenth century, some alchemists and naturalists
   >   were aware that ant hills gave off an acidic vapor. In 1671, English
   >   naturalist John Ray became the first person to describe the isolation
   >   of formic acid by the **distillation of large numbers of ants**. These
   >   insects secrete the substance for attack and defense purposes. Thus
   >   the name "formic acid" was coined from the Latin word for ant,
   >   *formica*.([newworldencyclopedia](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Formic_acid))

Comment: I'm now envisioning a new foodie trend: distilled red ant liquor...

Comment: Formic acid is the main culprit behind causing blindness from methanol exposure. Nature is not that forgiving.

Comment: And how did the name 'formica' for ant came by ?

Comment: @Sristy. Not clear. Some relate to a sanskrit word, meaning to give away (already knew they release a substance). Others to for (carrier) and mica (little speck).

Comment: @Sristy Formica is the Latin name for ant since the chemical was produced by distilling large number of ants, it was named formic acid. It is not the other way round.